# Why does 'do' (Red language native function) are changing the current execution path?

Tags: file, evaluation, red

**Introduction**

Let's assume that we have a project with structure like that:

```
project/
├── a.red
│
└───modules/
    ├── b.red
    └── c.red
```

Source code:

```
; -------- a.red --------
Red [ File: %a.red ]

b: do %modules/b.red
print b

c: do %modules/c.red
print c

; -------- modules/b.red --------
Red [ File: %b.red ]

return "B module loaded"

; -------- modules/c.red --------
Red [ File: %c.red ]

return "C module loaded"
```

What I am trying to do is:

- load files `modules/b.red` and `modules/c.red` into file `a.red`
- print loaded and evaluated content

I am using "**[do](http://www.red-by-example.org/#do)**" and "**[do-file](http://www.red-by-example.org/#do-file)**" functions from Red, but unexpectedly they change the current execution path after loading the first file from the `modules` subdirectory.

```
>> do %a.red
B module loaded
*** Access Error: cannot open: %modules/c.red
*** Where: read
*** Stack: do-file context do-file
```

As you can see `modules/b.red` file was successfully loaded, but `modules/c.red` not.

---

**Attempts**

Take a look at interesting output from the "**[pwd](http://www.red-by-example.org/#pwd)**" function, which displays the current path. After evaluating `modules/b.red` the path was changed, so I also changed `do %modules/c.red` to `do %c.red` to make it work.

```
; -------- a.red (modified) --------
Red [ File: %a.red ]

print pwd
b: do %modules/b.red
print b

print pwd
c: do %c.red
print c
```

Execution:

```
>> do %a.red
%/home/mateusz/Red/project/
B module loaded
%/home/mateusz/Red/project/modules/
C module loaded
```

The same situation I noticed with equivalent "**[do-file](http://www.red-by-example.org/#do-file)**" Red function.

I was using Red version: **0.6.3**.

---

**Questions**

Does somebody know why the "**[do](http://www.red-by-example.org/#do)**" function are changing the current execution path?

Maybe it is some issue or convention taken from Rebol ?

Any alternative solutions (if they does exists) will also be helpful.

Comment: I have not looked into Red's source code before, so according to your suggestion I checked it and finally I found the answer. Thanks to you, I discovered a new way of looking for answers - directly in the source code of Red ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you are calling `return` at the end of your scripts in the module/ directory. This is circumventing the end of script processing so the current working directory is not getting re-set at the end of the script.

`return` is only designed to be called from within a function.

Comment: Yes, exactly the `return` was the cause. I looked inside the **do-file** function implementation in Red source code, and that `return` affect exit before re-setting path to the the initial folder.

Thank you!

Comment: Note also that an issue has been opened for this, so it can be investigated further, and potentially change this behavior.